# to find a particular string alone using windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd, findstr

if my file conatins below text :

`sampleA1xxx sampleA2yyyy sampleA3zzzzz ... sampleA4hhhhh`

I want to find sampleA4 and display sampleA4hhhh using windows batch script.

Thats is my output should be: `sampleA4hhhhh`

Could anyone please help me.

Comment: As far as I know, unless there is some sort of consistency such as a common letter separating all the samples (this includes a space) this is not possible. Note if each case is "A[number]" then it may be possible, however if there is no sort of consistency then it is not.

Comment: ^^sampleA1xxx ^^sampleA2yyyy ^^sampleA3zzzzz ^^sampleA4hhhhh if this is the case then there is ^^symbol always separating each entity...Is it possible now...

Answer (score 2):

take a batch or have a look at GNUWin [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
>type file
^^sampleA1xxx ^^sampleA2yyyy ^^sampleA3zzzzz ^^sampleA4hhhhh

>sed -r "s/.*(\b\w+4\w+)/\1/" file
sampleA4hhhhh
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set target=sampleA4
set len=8
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "%target%" theFile.txt') do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      set word=%%b
      if "!word:~0,%len%!" equ "%target%" (
         echo !word:~%len%!
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (q17316008.txt) DO SET line=%%i
SET line=%line:^= %
SET line=%line:*sampleA4=sampleA4%
FOR %%i IN (%line:^^= %) DO SET line=%%i&GOTO :done
:done
ECHO %line%

GOTO :EOF
```

This should do what I gather to be the task. It assumes that the `"samplea4"` string exists in the file's single line, is case-insensitive and the line doesn't exceed the ~8K limit on line length.

Simply replace the carets with spaces, lop off the leading characters to the first occurrence of the target string, and process that target string as a list; the first element will be the required string, so stop the processing when it's available.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried this myself with a similar case and it worked fine:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=^^" %%a in (seperate.txt) do (echo %%a)
pause
```

Note: This is designed for a batch file, and replace the 4 after "tokens=" with whichever separated text you want to stop at.

Hope this helped,

Yours Mona.

Comment: its not working for me . :(...Actually i need to find a keyword xxyyzzzz11.20.2 and get the version 11.20.2..

Comment: Did u replace "seperate.txt" with your file name?

Comment: hmm... I don't understand completely, but if you can find another consistency in the file, replace the `=^^` with `=[whatever separates each instance]`